# When using scoped styles in Vuejs is it possible to supply the signature string?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

When you use a scoped style in Vuejs it includes a data-v-XXX string with a specific signature.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>this is a title</h1>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

You get a generated style of

```
h1[data-v-3fe14d6d] {
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
}

p[data-v-3fe14d6d] {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Is there any way to supply the signature string that is injected into the data-v string? So you could have data-v-MyCustomControlName.

As mentioned below the primary reason I am looking to supply a specific string is to allow for third party style injections.

While the values for the data-v-XXXX could be used for this purpose and would guarantee no collisions the generated numbers are awkward to work with.

I should perhaps change the question to "What is the best way to use Nuxtjs to minimize style collisions and while maximizing third party style support?"

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to have a custom name? Vue will inject those custom "GUIDs" for you - this is how you get the "scoped" styles without naming collision. I assume there is a reason you want to rename them?

Comment: "Mainly" to allow third party style customization, either "directly" or through something like user-styles.org.

I am currently trying to try set up and and use <style module="named_prefix"> to see if this will meet my needs.

Comment: You can still do this without worrying about those names... Can you provide an example of how your needs are not being met?

Comment: I am aware of at least 3 ways to do what I would like to do. All of them are using a manual scheme to scope the css. The most direct is adding a class to a wrapping div and using .namedclass h1 and .namedclass p in the style tag. I could also used named classes in the tags directly. h1.namedclass and p.namedclass. It appears using module="named_prefix" will take the named prefix and add to to any named style so h1 class="blog-post-title" would be create .named_prefix.blog-post-title in the generated html and css. Which you could also do manually without the module="named_prefix" option.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is not possible.

Comment: Can you point to documentation or a test that shows this is not possible?

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything that outright says "you can't do this".. I have found official documentation that states Vue will add that unique attribute.. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/comparison.html#Component-Scoped-CSS (I have also taken Vue courses and none of them mention being able to modify this... it doesn't really make sense to allow them to be editable, it's kind of an anti-pattern)...

Comment: I'll wait to see if there is an alternative to "no"

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments above I can think of 3 ways to solve this problem manually if providing the signature string is not possible.

The draw back to all of these are that they are manual process. Also Vue will still have some style collisions if you choose a name that is used in other code. For example if you use the class name 'wrapper' your class will still collide with any other 'wrapper' class. So named classes will still need to be unique.

1. Use a wrapper with a named class.
   This will allow for targeting the children and still have scoped styles. This is the simplest but also the most likely to have collisions.

```
<template>
  <div class="class-for-scoped-styles">
    <h1>this is a title</h1>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.class-for-scoped-styles h1 {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}

.class-for-scoped-styles p {
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

2. Add scoped names to each tag.
   A bit less likely to have collision problems.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="class-for-scoped-styles">this is a title</h1>
    <p class="class-for-scoped-styles">this is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
h1.class-for-scoped-styles {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}

p.class-for-scoped-styles {
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

3. Use a named prefix and a named classes for each tag.
   I believe this manually doing what the  using css modules - but doing it manually.
   This is least likely to incur collisions but also is the most verbose and easiest to inject manual coding errors.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="class-for-scoped-styles blog-entry-title">this is a title</h1>
    <p class="class-for-scoped-styles blog-entry-description">this is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.class-for-scoped-styles.blog-entry-title {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}

.class-for-scoped-styles.blog-entry-description {
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

All these would allow for scoped styles and still allow for easy theme insertion or third party custom styles. I'm still looking into using css modules and that might ultimately be the best solution.